# Процент зарплаты работников по отделению

Tags: sql, oracle

Мне нужно посчитать какую часть заработной платы в процентном отношении получает каждый сотрудник в рамках отдела, в котором он работает используя аналитические функции

```
SELECT EMPLOYEES.FIRST_NAME, EMPLOYEES.LAST_NAME, EMPLOYEES.DEPARTMENT_ID, 
DEPARTMENTS.DEPARTMENT_NAME, EMPLOYEES.SALARY,
(SALARY/SUM(SALARY)) * 100  over (partition by DEPARTMENT_ID) AS "Percent1"
FROM HR.EMPLOYEES
FULL JOIN HR.DEPARTMENTS ON EMPLOYEES.DEPARTMENT_ID = DEPARTMENTS.DEPARTMENT_ID
```

В данном случае я не знаю что сделал неправильно но пишет что FROM поставлен неправильно, помогите разобраться где его надо поставить и вообще может все ли я правильно пытался делать

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: в данном случае вы скобки поставили неправильно

Comment: а как надо     то ставить